# Changes not being saved back to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to connect to my NorthwindDataSet, when the user clicks the button I want the data to be saved back to the database. When I run the code below I get no errors but the data is not saved. I think I am connecting to the DataSet correctly and am not sure why this isn't saving back.

```
NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter north = new NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter();
NorthwindDataSet.CustomersDataTable northtable = north.GetData();

NorthwindDataSet northwindDataSet1 = new NorthwindDataSet();
NorthwindDataSet.CustomersRow newCustomersRow =
northwindDataSet1.Customers.NewCustomersRow();

newCustomersRow.CustomerID = "5";
newCustomersRow.CompanyName = "Alfreds Futterkiste";

northwindDataSet1.Customers.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow);

northwindDataSet1.Customers.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used this stuff but what's the connection between your DataSet and the DataAdapter? I'd expect the CustomersTableAdapter instance to be doing the update via Update() or a custom method.

Comment: Don't you need to call the Update method on the TableAdapter north?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit changes not only by AcceptChanges method but use Update method on table adapter.

In your case it will look like this:

```
north.update(northwindDataSet1.Customers);
northwindDataSet1.Customers.AcceptChanges();
```

Accept changes do not commit data to database. Update does.

Comment: It looks like your are trying to set primary key, so by default framework prevents you from this (since PK should be auto-generated). I think you would have to alter INSERT query and parameters. Considering of course that there is no identity field defined in DB, which again will stop you from updating PK column on DB level.